# Find out which tables are going to accessed by a mysql query (beforehand)

Tags: php, mysql

Hy, I have a arbitrary sql query. Starting from this query I want to know which tables this query would access or change. There could be some functions or triggers defined which change additionally other tables than the on stated in the query.

I thought about creating a different mysql server where I send the query to. But then the tables would need to be created beforehand, but which?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Isn't this what [transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) are for? Since you can't parse the query due to functions and triggers you can do a transaction, find out which tables where affected and do a `ROLLBACK` if you don't want to commit.

Comment: If it is truly an arbitrary query, then you would need a sql parser.  Look into ANTLR?

Comment: Would something like this help: https://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/

Comment: Thx for your comments. Transactions are (unluckily) not work as I'm working with the MyISAM storage engine. A sql parser won't give me the changed tables by a trigger. But I guess it's the best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run an [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) on the query and it shows the plan and all the tables that are going to be used. So it would would be:

```
EXPLAIN yourqueryhere
```

Comment: That looks very promising. It seems like I have to do some parsing there as well, for derived tables as I get something like this:


`id select_type table type ...
1 PRIMARY <derived2> ALL ...
1 PRIMARY domain eq_ref PRIMARY ...
2 DERIVED by_domainid_and_day Using temporary; Using filesort` (I hope this table is going to be readable)

Comment: This is the easiest approach you can get all the rows under the table column to see what tables are being used. and rows columns numbers for the count of records retrieved from each table. EXPLAIN is mostly used for query optimization but it fits your need in this case

Comment: When I have a query which request tables from multiple databases the database isn't included in the table name. like above by_domainid_and_day is coming from stats-db where i'm currently in tmp-db. Do you know how to circumvent this flaw.

Comment: A cheap way to get around it is to give aliases to the tables with their db name so after each table type as 'dbname.tablename'

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how you have it. If it's something like (Select * from X join Y on blah blah) you could just parse the data and retrieve the table names.

```
$string = "select * from table_name join table_name_2 on table_name_2.id = table_name.table_name_2_id join table_name_3 blah blah";
preg_match_all('/(?<=from|join|update )\S+/i', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Comment: You need to filter out subqueries, e.g. `from (select ...`.